# How can I speed up my query for mongodb? (I use mongodriver repo for. net core)

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I only query a specific date range for **500.000** data but it takes about 15-20 minutes.

I used **linq** but the result is the same..

use repo link : https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver

my codes:

```
result = await collection
                               .Find(filter)
                               .Sort(sortBy)
                               .Skip(skip * limit)
                               .Limit(limit)
                               .ToListAsync();
```

Edit 1: We focused on the server. I hope the problem is solved. As far as I see, access through the server is slow, but it is not about server features, but about the layers in between.

Edit 2: My test result;

```
find({ "createDate" : { "$lte" : ISODate("2020-07-31T23:59:59.59Z"), "$gte" : ISODate("2020-07-01T00:00:00Z") } }).skip(0).limit(1000000).explain()

{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "*",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "createDate" : {
                                                "$lte" : ISODate("2020-07-31T23:59:59.590Z")
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "createDate" : {
                                                "$gte" : ISODate("2020-07-01T00:00:00Z")
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "LIMIT",
                        "limitAmount" : 1000000,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "createDate" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "createDate",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                                "createDate" : [ ]
                                        },
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "createDate" : [
                                                        "[new Date(1593561600000), new Date(1596239999590)]"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "*",
                "port" : *,
                "version" : "4.0.11",
                "gitVersion" : "*"
        },
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1597918530, 1),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1597918530, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the generated sql?

Comment: Did you put index on your collection ? If not, for performance, you better put indexes on the collection you query against; and,  include your (sort) and (filter) fields in the index. If you can share a sample query and document; we can suggest and index.

Comment: Yes i add index. @SafakUlusoy and example query: { "createDate" : { "$lte" : ISODate("2020-08-13T23:59:59.59Z"), "$gte" : ISODate("2020-08-01T00:00:00Z") } }

Comment: @RandRandom yes i did.

Comment: @childofthealgorithm thanks, can you also write you index definition/script ? Maybe we can see some improvement point.

Comment: Run the query using `explain` with the execution stats option and edit the output into the question.

Comment: @SafakUlusoy I don't think the problem is caused by mongo. For 22000 records, only 30 milliseconds query runs. I think the problem is caused by the mongo driver for c #.

Comment: @Joe I don't think the problem is caused by mongo. For 22000 records, only 30 milliseconds query runs. I think the problem is caused by the mongo driver for c #.

Comment: Get a faster machine with more memory that is dedicated to running a database.  People think any machine can uses to run a database.  A large database requires the bast machine you can find with a largest amount of memory and the fastest disk.  The easiest think to solve is to make sure the database is installed on the database local machine and not a network drive.

Comment: @jdweng You may be right. local mongodb brings it very fast. I will continue our tests and share the results

Comment: Is local database same size as the remote? The driver only affects the speed of the data transferred and not lookup time.   So  you have to compare apples to apples  when comparing time which is the amount of data transferred and the size of database.

Comment: @jdweng yes same size :)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to speed up your database is to start by profiling what is going off. You can enable profiling by executing the following on the database.

```js
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

This will create a `system.profile` collection in your database in which you can query like any other collection.

```
db.system.profile.find()
```

More information on this can be found on the [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#example-profiler-data-queries).

Once you understand what's taking a long time you'll be able to figure out what indexes are worth adding to support the queries that are being executed.

I also find it useful to set the Application Name property on the mongo client settings in C# so that you can see what/where the queries are coming from. This can be done as below.

```cs
var client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientSettings
{
    ApplicationName = "StackoverflowExampleApp"
});

var db = client.GetDatabase("test");

var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("test");

var findFluent = await collection.Find(FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>.Empty)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Then if we set up the profiler and take a look.
we'll see our appName in the profile document

```js
db.system.profile.find().pretty()
{
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "test.test",
        "command" : {
                "find" : "test",
                "filter" : {

                },
                "$db" : "test",
                "lsid" : {
                        "id" : UUID("9a49130c-7086-46c4-a564-a5ee4fbfc2a1")
                }
        },
        "keysExamined" : 0,
        "docsExamined" : 3,
        "cursorExhausted" : true,
        "numYield" : 0,
        "nreturned" : 3,
        "locks" : {
                "ReplicationStateTransition" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "w" : NumberLong(1)
                        }
                },
                "Global" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(1)
                        }
                },
                "Database" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(1)
                        }
                },
                "Collection" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(1)
                        }
                },
                "Mutex" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(1)
                        }
                }
        },
        "flowControl" : {

        },
        "responseLength" : 224,
        "protocol" : "op_msg",
        "millis" : 2,
        "planSummary" : "COLLSCAN",
        "execStats" : {
                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 3,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 5,
                "advanced" : 3,
                "needTime" : 1,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 0,
                "restoreState" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "docsExamined" : 3
        },
        "ts" : ISODate("2020-08-14T09:20:11.323Z"),
        "client" : "127.0.0.1",
        "appName" : "StackoverflowExampleApp",
        "allUsers" : [ ],
        "user" : ""
}
```

and you'll be able to search for your app in the logs as

```js
db.system.profile.find({ appName: "StackoverflowExampleApp" }).pretty()
```

Comment: I followed these steps and I did not get any results regarding the slowness of the query

Comment: What results did you get? Is you query utilizing indexes with IXScan and how many records is it having to scan before getting the results etc...?

Comment: Yes , i did, Can you show me a sample reading? how do i read the results what exactly is it telling me what performance loss is?